# awk how to concatenate string in for loop and print from END section

Tags: awk

Problem: "**a**" variable printed from END section has only last found line and not all lines

file1:

```
pattern .........
irrelevant text
irrelevant text
pattern .........
pattern .........
irrelevant text
```

awk code:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NR; i++)
       if ($i ~ /^pattern/) a+=$0 
     }
     END {print $a}' file1
```

From END section i want to print only lines with pattern

Comment: What are you trying to do? What output are you expecting? Your code doesn't make much sense (`$a` is a field, `NR` is the line number, not the number of fields, `a+=` is an arithmetic addition), so it's hard to guess what output you want to see from that code.

Comment: @terdon question edited

Comment: Is `pattern` always the first field? Do you really have empty spaces before the first word on every line? Do you just need `grep -w '^pattern' file1`?

Comment: @terdon there are no spaces, need awk because of printing order from end secition - I will add another patterns

Comment: Then please remove the spaces. And show us the output you expect. There is no printing order here that would be different in `grep`.

Comment: I suspect `a` stubbornly stays at 0 because all the matches you add to it begin with a non-numeric. When you hit END, `$a` evaluates as `$0`, which represents the whole line last read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to collect all lines that matches a particular pattern, and then print them at the end.

You can do that with

```
awk '/^pattern/ { a[++n] = $0 }
     END { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print a[i] }' file
```

This uses `a` as an array and adds each line matching the pattern as a new entry in the array.  At the end, a loop iterates over the entries of `a` and prints each.

If you want to look for the exact literal string `pattern` in the first column instead of matching a regular expression against the whole line, use `$1 == "pattern"` as the condition.

However, if this is *all* you want to do, then it's easier to just use

```
awk '/^pattern/' file
```

or, if you want to match the literal string `pattern` in the first column,

```
awk '$1 == "pattern"' file
```

This would invoke the default action for each line that matches the pattern, or contains `pattern` as the first column if you use the second variation.  The "default action" is to print the line.

---

In `awk`, `a += $0` would be an arithmetic operation that increments the value of `a` by the current line, interpreted as a number.  To concatenate line as a string to the variable `a`, you would have used `a = a $0`, or `a = a ORS $0` if you want to insert a newline (the default value of `ORS`) before the string that you append.  Neither of these is what I believe you want to do here though.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed: `a = a"\n" $0`

Comment: @EdiD I don't think so. It would be more convenient to use an array, if you have to store the data at all. For starters, it would be easier to avoid adding a newline before the first matching line.

Comment: My question is simple example. I have to print with order like this: lines with pattern1 on top and lines with pattern2 on bottom (so I use variable "a" and "b" and place in END section) and your suggestion is working pretty well.

Comment: Nevertheless, arrays would be preferred because the string append will take longer and longer as it extends. If your arrays were A, B, ... to correspond with patterns reA, reB, ...; and you had a function Show (arg) to call twice in the END statement, it would be tidier.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

1. You want to access all lines of the files to test for matching pattern, but you do so in one rule block (`{ ... }`). However all rules are processed *for every line of the file*, and inside such a rule, you only have access to the content of the currently processed line. The code

   ```
   { for (i=1; i<=NR; i++)
      if ($i ~ /^pattern/) a+=$0 
   }
   ```

   would therefore try (for all lines of the file since it is not preceded by a condition) to test *fields* number 1 to `NR` - where `NR` is the *number of the current line inside the file*, not the number of fields, which would be `NF` - of the current line, but attempts to append *the entire current line* to the variable `a` every time that happens. This may not mess up the result if the pattern really can only appear at the beginning of the line as your RegExp implies (due to the `^` anchor), but is at least extremely inefficient.
2. In your attempt to append the current line to `a`, you write

   ```
   a+=$0
   ```

   However, this is only well-defined if the line (or at least the first space-separated field) can be interpreted correctly as a number, in which case `a` will be the sum of the numbers on all the lines containing only/beginning with a single number that appear in your file. If no line can be interpreted as a number, the value of `a` in the end will be "0".
3. In the `END` block, you state

   ```
   print $a
   ```

   This however will print the *field number `a`* of the current line, not the content of the variable `a`. Since your variable `a`, however, is "0" as explained in point 2, this will refer to the entire current line (a.k.a `$0`). And since references to field numbers in the `END` block always refer to the last line of the file (for lack of a "current" line at end-of-file), this statement will inevitably print the entire last line of the file and nothing else.

Since you only seem interested in printing lines that match a certain pattern, it could be easier to use `grep` instead, which is dedicated for this type of task.

Comment: Regarding `grep`, yes, that may be easier, but it depends on whether `pattern` is a regular expression or a fixed string. If it's a fixed string, it may still be easier with `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print all lines whose first field is `pattern`, there is no need to store things in memory, you can just print each line as you find it:

```
awk '$1=="pattern"' file
```

Or even

```
grep -w '^pattern' file
```

If, instead, you want to print each line if *any* of the line's fields are `pattern`, use:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if($i=="pattern"){ print; next}}}' file
```

Alternatively, if you are just looking for cases where the field's value *starts* with `pattern`, but can have other characters afterwards (which is what your code was attempting), use this if you only want the first field:

```
awk '$1~/^pattern/' file
```

and this for any field:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if($i~/^pattern/){ print; next}}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want concatenation of all those lines that matches with `^pattern`, so this would do what you need:

```
echo $(grep '^pattern' infile)
```

same with `awk`:

```
echo $(awk '/^pattern/' infile)
```

or using `awk` only:

```
awk '/^pattern/{ line = (line? line FS $0: $0) }  END{ print line }' infile
```